# Multi version support in device Vocabulary

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, architecture

Quick background:

- I have a device which is used in IoT.
- This device runs on a IoT protocol.
- The device is able to control and monitor from different sensors in the building and some similar operations.
- A device has basic properties/params like name, present value, type, and description. These are standard parameters. Each device version has its own set of parameters stored in separate files called **device vocabularies**. There are three versions of these vocabularies for different device versions.
- These vocabs create an issue for me when these devices are under a parent, because I cannot connect different child types with a parent.
  At parent level I need to support all vocabs independently.
  And I cannot make any changes in the child devices due to limitations of child devices.

Illustration:

Current Scenario:

Parent1(with vocab_1)  ---> Child_1(with vocab_1) ------- Works fine

Parent1(with vocab_1) ---> Child_2(with vocab_2) -------- Fault/Will not work

What I want:

Parent1(with 3 different vocabs simultaneously) ---> Child_1(with voacb_1) -------- Will work fine

Parent1(with 3 different vocabs simultaneously) ---> Child_2(with voacb_2) -------- Will work fine

Can anyone please suggest how I can proceed with the architecture/design.